# How do I bypass password in Ubuntu on A1224

Tags: macos, imac, password

I was given an A1224 iMac for my 5-8th grade students. The previous owner said he could not remember the password. It has Ubuntu on it. When I hit <kbd>alt</kbd> at boot up it shows one drive. I click on the arrow and it says there’s nothing there or something and just boots into Ubuntu again.

I have a Windows keyboard in case you give me board commands. <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> don’t do anything.

The goal is to get an os loaded to use it with my students. I would like whatever Apple OS (or another that’s easy to install) I could put on it for free or as inexpensive as possible.

Is there a guide to erase this and then set up an OS for learning?

Comment: Try this to see if you can find the exact model designation here - [Ultimate Mac Lookup](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/). The A1234-style numbers often cover many years of different models - & the iMacs of that time '07-'09 are on the cusp of being able to boot from USB stick; if it's too early it will only boot from CD.

Comment: Apple hardware works fine with PC keyboards for shift key which is the only one needed if you [just need to reset the root Ubuntu password](https://vitux.com/ubuntu-reset-root-password/). We might need more details edited into your question if the question is more about erasing and getting an OS going. I would pursue Ubuntu specific guidance on password resets. Hopefully you don’t need to triage a hardware / keyboard or other issue as well as navigate password reset.

Comment: I have by trying your solution in a virtual machine. After correcting what I believe to be two obvious errors in the linked instructions, I fail to see how this would fix the OP login issue. I assume the current owner cannot login because the correct password cannot be entered at the login screen. The instructions state how to change the root password. What do you do after that?  I have not been able to change any other user passwords before rebooting at step 4. After rebooting, I cannot login as root or any other user from the login screen.

Comment: @Tetsujin: I can answer your concerns. I have a 2007 iMac A1224. You can boot an El Capitan USB installer from my machine. I would assume this would also be true for the 2008 and 2009 model years. Note also that you cannot BIOS boot a standard 64-bit Ubuntu installer from the optical drive. You can however EFI boot same DVD. You can EFI boot a standard 64-bit Ubuntu installer from USB. Once could conclude that most likely Ubuntu would have been installed to EFI boot, which would explain why the shift key does not work.

Comment: It was a long shot, hopefully they can discard some of the worries about keyboard and refine the question to one that works other than try to install a new OS on Mac or raspberry pi or whatever is around. Inheriting someone else’s OS is tricky enough on known working hardware @DavidAnderson like you’ve got with your EFI boot experience.

Comment: I just want to be able to use it with my students. I would like whatever Apple iOS I could put on it for free or as inexpensive as possible.

Comment: If anyone feels after the edit all comments should be deleted, please flag for moderator attention. We could move them to chat or just start over…

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this answer instead of a lengthy sequence of comments or attempting to use chat. I have the following questions for Casey to answer. I realize Casey may not be able to currently answer some of the questions.

- How much memory is installed in the Mac? If you could either login to the existing Ubuntu or install another operating system, then the question could be answered. I want to know the answer, because the latest Ubuntu requires at least 4 GB of memory and no standard A1224 Mac was shipped from Apple with this much memory.
- Which year is the Mac? My A1224 Mac is a Mid 2007 Mac. It would be helpful to know the year (Mid 2007, Early 2008, Early 2009 or Mid 2009) of your Mac. The serial number is printed on the foot of the iMac. You can enter the serial number at the Apple web site [Check your device's coverage](https://checkcoverage.apple.com/) to get the year of the Mac.
- Which version of Ubuntu is installed. I assume to determine this you would need to login to the Mac.
- Are there any other computers available, So a bootable install media could be created. I would need to know the operating system(s) installed.

The following operating systems are or have been installed on my 2007 iMac. This is not a complete list. Note, this Mac has been upgraded to 4 GB of memory and a 1 TB HDD.

- Apple OS X El Capitan. Apple provides this operating system free of charge for Mac users. This 64 bit operating system was installed using a USB flash drive. El Capitan is also capable of running 32 bit compatible software. Once a bootable El Capitan USB flash drive installer has been created, the installation procedure is relatively simple. While this is the latest operating system that Apple offers for your Mac, El Capitan is a relatively old and outdated. (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_version_history#Releases) for releases since OS X El Capitan.) For example, the Safari web browser version included with El Capitan is to old to access most modern web sites. However, there still are free third party web browsers, whose current release is compatible with El Capitan. The example, there is [Pale Moon](https://www.palemoon.org/), which I tested by installing and viewing this question, but have no idea how good the application actually is.
- Microsoft Windows 10. This was a 64 bit, BIOS booting install which used the Windows Support Software that Apple provides for a 32 bit Windows 7 install. This requires the purchase of a Windows 10 license. The installation procedure is rather difficult. Note: Windows 10 is due for [retirement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-10-home-and-pro#:%7E:text=Windows%2010%20will%20reach%20end,update%20releases%20through%20that%20date.) on Oct 14, 2025. I do not remember which Windows 10 release was installed, but it was not any of the current releases. Windows 10 is not currently installed on the 2007 iMac.
- Canonical Ubuntu 22.04.3. Canonical provides this operating system free of charge, but does take donations. This is the current 64 bit LTS desktop release, which requires 4 GB of memory. **If your Mac does not have 4 GB of memory, there are other Ubuntu variants you could install which require less memory.** An EFI booting install is relatively easy from a USB flash drive installer.  A did not test installation from a DVD, because the ISO size would have required burning a DL DVD. I did burn a RW DVD using the smaller 64 bit Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS desktop iso file. I was able to confirm the 2007 iMac could not BIOS boot from either the Ubuntu 22.04.3 USB installer or Ubuntu 20.04.6 DVD installer. I confirmed EFI booting from the Ubuntu 20.04.6 DVD installer, but did not test an actual install from this DVD. There are procedures posted as answers here a Ask Different and Ask Ubuntu, which can be used to install a 64 bit BIOS booting Ubuntu. However, the procedures are either outdated or difficult to implement.

I would also note that I was able to change the password for an existing account on an Ubuntu install on my 2007 iMac without first entering the current password. So to be clear, an answer to your question *"How do I bypass password in Ubuntu on A1224?"* has been found at least for the 64 bit, EFI booting Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. If you still want to do this, then post a comment.